# Why index scan can be slow in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan

I have a query:

```sql
WITH route_ids_filtered_by_shipments AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        rts.route_id
    FROM
        route_to_shipment rts
    JOIN
        shipment s
            ON rts.shipment_id = s.shipment_id
    WHERE
        s.store_sender_id = ANY('{"a2342659-5f2f-11eb-85a3-1c34dae33151","7955ab25-0511-11ee-885e-08c0eb32014b","319ce173-2614-11ee-b10a-08c0eb31fffb","4bdddeb3-5ec9-11ee-b10a-08c0eb31fffb","8e6054c5-6db3-11ea-9786-0050560307be","485dc39c-debc-11ed-885e-08c0eb32014b","217d0f7b-78de-11ea-a214-0050560307be","a5a8a21a-9b9a-11ec-b0fc-08c0eb31fffb","79e7d5be-ef8b-11eb-a0ee-ec0d9a21b021","3f35d68a-1212-11ec-85ad-1c34dae33151","087bcf22-5f30-11eb-85a3-1c34dae33151","c065e1c8-a679-11eb-85a9-1c34dae33151"}'::uuid[])
)
SELECT
    r.acceptance_status
,   count(*) count
FROM
    route r
JOIN
    route_ids_filtered_by_shipments rifs
        ON r.route_id = rifs.route_id
WHERE
    r.acceptance_status <> 'ERRORED'::route_acceptance_status
GROUP BY
    r.acceptance_status;
```

Its execution plan (obtained via EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS):

```
HashAggregate  (cost=579359.05..579359.09 rows=4 width=12) (actual time=6233.281..6669.596 rows=3 loops=1)
  Group Key: r.acceptance_status
  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24kB
  Buffers: shared hit=14075979 read=573570
  I/O Timings: shared/local read=19689.039
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=564249.11..578426.89 rows=186432 width=4) (actual time=6064.176..6658.862 rows=69460 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (r.route_id = rts.route_id)
        Buffers: shared hit=14075979 read=573570
        I/O Timings: shared/local read=19689.039
        ->  Seq Scan on route r  (cost=0.00..13526.16 rows=248230 width=20) (actual time=0.015..112.580 rows=248244 loops=1)
              Filter: (acceptance_status <> 'ERRORED'::route_acceptance_status)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 7879
              Buffers: shared hit=5112 read=3492
              I/O Timings: shared/local read=35.687
        ->  Hash  (cost=561844.75..561844.75 rows=192349 width=16) (actual time=6063.413..6499.725 rows=69460 loops=1)
              Buckets: 262144  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 5304kB
              Buffers: shared hit=14070867 read=570078
              I/O Timings: shared/local read=19653.352
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=557997.77..559921.26 rows=192349 width=16) (actual time=6038.518..6487.332 rows=69460 loops=1)
                    Group Key: rts.route_id
                    Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10257kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=14070867 read=570078
                    I/O Timings: shared/local read=19653.352
                    ->  Gather  (cost=1001.02..555707.18 rows=916234 width=16) (actual time=0.976..6341.587 rows=888024 loops=1)
                          Workers Planned: 7
                          Workers Launched: 7
                          Buffers: shared hit=14070867 read=570078
                          I/O Timings: shared/local read=19653.352
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.02..463083.78 rows=130891 width=16) (actual time=1.576..5990.903 rows=111003 loops=8)
                                Buffers: shared hit=14070867 read=570078
                                I/O Timings: shared/local read=19653.352
                                ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using route_to_shipment_pkey on route_to_shipment rts  (cost=0.56..78746.01 rows=517565 width=32) (actual time=0.050..733.728 rows=452894 loops=8)
                                      Heap Fetches: 401042
                                      Buffers: shared hit=94576 read=38851
                                      I/O Timings: shared/local read=2255.435
                                ->  Index Scan using shipment_pkey on shipment s  (cost=0.46..0.74 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=3623151)
                                      Index Cond: (shipment_id = rts.shipment_id)
"                                      Filter: (store_sender_id = ANY ('{a2342659-5f2f-11eb-85a3-1c34dae33151,7955ab25-0511-11ee-885e-08c0eb32014b,319ce173-2614-11ee-b10a-08c0eb31fffb,4bdddeb3-5ec9-11ee-b10a-08c0eb31fffb,8e6054c5-6db3-11ea-9786-0050560307be,485dc39c-debc-11ed-885e-08c0eb32014b,217d0f7b-78de-11ea-a214-0050560307be,a5a8a21a-9b9a-11ec-b0fc-08c0eb31fffb,79e7d5be-ef8b-11eb-a0ee-ec0d9a21b021,3f35d68a-1212-11ec-85ad-1c34dae33151,087bcf22-5f30-11eb-85a3-1c34dae33151,c065e1c8-a679-11eb-85a9-1c34dae33151}'::uuid[]))"
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                      Buffers: shared hit=13976291 read=531227
                                      I/O Timings: shared/local read=17397.917
"Settings: effective_cache_size = '256GB', effective_io_concurrency = '250', max_parallel_workers = '24', max_parallel_workers_per_gather = '8', random_page_cost = '1', seq_page_cost = '1.2', work_mem = '128MB'"
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=16
Planning Time: 0.409 ms
Execution Time: 6670.976 ms
```

My task it to make query be executed within 1 sec, at least.
I can observe in the plan(basing on my current knowledge about PG query optimization) that some nodes have a high number of heap fetches and it could be cured with VACCUM on a table.
What I'm trying to comprehend:

1. Why PG chose join's `ON` predicate `rts.shipment_id = shipment_id` as a base for building set of rows and performed filtering by `store_sender_id` over that set if there is a separate index on the `shipment.store_sender_id` column which is highly selective. In my understanding, to find a relative small number of rows matched by `store_sender_id`and filter by `rts.shipment_id = shipment_id` would be a waaaay faster. Or there could be union of bitmap index scans (via BitmapAnd).
2. > Index Scan using shipment_pkey on shipment s  (cost=0.46..0.74 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=3623151)

If I multiply actual total time by `loops` counter to get actual time I get near 40 sec, when the query completes within 7 sec. How could it be???

Comment: Here's the more readable [explain analyze on depesz](https://explain.depesz.com/s/Nhd2)

Comment: Can you please show exact index definitions? Also post EXPLAIN ANALYZE for: SELECT DISTINCT shipment_id FROM shipment s WHERE s.store_sender_id = ANY(your big list)

Comment: Having random_page_cost set to lower than seq_page_cost is totally insane.  Of course it will lead to demented plans.

Comment: "If I multiply actual total time by loops counter to get actual time I get near 40 sec, when the query completes within 7 sec."   You have 8 parallel processes.  It only takes 5 seconds of clock time for them to spend 40 seconds doing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index scan is taking a long time because

1. it is repeated very often
2. there are not enough index columns, so PostgreSQL has to fetch the table rows.

Try this index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON shipment (shipment_id, store_sender_id);
VACUUM shipment;
```

Frequent `VACUUM` is required to keep the index-only scan efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it. Do you have any idea, why planner totally ignore separate index on `store_sender_id`? I expected that there will be bitmap scan or something :(

Comment: Probably because it would have been even slower.